# serial port (winAPI) : couldnt receive any data

Tags: winapi, serial-port

I'm working with sending a char 'a' from pc to MCU and return it back to PC through serial communication. Precisely, it should display 'a' but there is nothing display.
I have tested on hyperterminal and it works fine.

If there is any problem with my code please point it out. Thank you.

It works fine on sending a char I guess so I post only a part of my code.

```
DWORD dwCommModemStatus;
DWORD dwBytesTransferred;
DWORD bytesWritten;
char receivedData[2] = {0};

char data= 'a';
bool sendChar = WriteFile(hSerial,&data,1,&bytesWritten,NULL);
if(!sendChar){
    printf("WriteFile ERROR\n");
}

SetCommMask(hSerial,EV_RXCHAR);
WaitCommEvent(hSerial, &dwCommModemStatus,0);

if(dwCommModemStatus & EV_RXCHAR){
    if(!ReadFile(hSerial,receivedData,1,&dwBytesTransferred,0)){
        printf("ReadFile Error\n");
    }else{
        printf("%c\n",receivedData[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is WaitCommEvent returning TRUE?

Comment: Getting the serial port setup wrong is the typical explanation, especially for the handshake lines.  Use SysInternals' PortMon to compare Hyperterminal to your code.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.
patriiice -> I have test it and it returns TRUE
Hans-> Maybe there is something wrong with my setup. I want to post my whole code, isn't better for me to create a new thread?

Comment: What is the value of `dwCommModemStatus` when `WaitCommEvent` returns?

Answer (score 0):

I think `WaitForSingleObject` is missing in your code above.

If `WaitCommEvent` returns `false` you have to wait. You can do this with `WaitForSingleObject`. If this method returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0` you can use `ReadFile`.

Please see [WaitForSingleObject function (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [Wait Functions (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: That's only needed when using overlapped IO. The code they included is passing 0 meaning they aren't using overlapped IO.